# Invisible GCC optimization flags?

Tags: c, gcc, optimization

I'm building some large project using **GCC 4.4.2**. Since I want to build it for release, I use `-O1` GCC optimization flag, but unluckily it messes somehow with my code, and the final binaries do not work as expected, when building with `-O0` flag (or no optimization) everything works fine. 
I had a similar problem with my project before, in that time it was the `-fstrict-aliasing` flag that caused troubles on `-O2` optimization level, I managed to find that it was caused by that specific flag by making a search on all flags that are mentioned in this documentation, regarding the `-O2` optimization level:

http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.4.2/gcc/Optimize-Options.html

Now I tried to do the same with the list they mention regarding the `-O1` flag, but unfortunately it seems that not all the flags mentioned, or there are some hidden flags being enabled, because when I compile with just `-O1` flag or with just a list of the provided flags (without putting `-O1` itself) I get different compilation results, and my binaries refuse to work only with the specific `-O1` flag, so I can't find the exact troublemaking option.

Is it possible to know what hidden options the `-O1` option includes, and how can I disable some of them?

Comment: It sounds like you're invoking undefined behaviour. Perhaps it would be better to enable -Wall and -Wextra and try to correct the code?

Comment: Most probably side effects, sequence points and/or (un)strict aliasing in your code.

Comment: gcc 4.4.2 was released long time ago. Why don't you try gcc 4.8 or newer

Comment: There are a number of things that are done based on the optimization level that don't have any individual matching flag. Better fix your code than try to find what compiler flag hides the bugs.

Answer (score 1):

You can run `gcc -Q -v` on a small C file to have GCC dump the options being used.
Run it with and without the `-O1` option to get the difference between the enabled options.